# Local development with docker compose - Using Mysql localhost

Tags: mysql, docker, localhost, docker-compose, development-environment

I am a beginner with Docker and docker-compose for local development on my Mac.  Currently, if I restart my containers, the MySql data is wiped out.

I would like to enable persistent storage for MySql local development.

Is there a way I can connect my application running inside docker container to the MySql running on my Mac Host machine?

My `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
   mysql:
        build: ./mysql
        container_name: mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
```

Apart from connecting docker application to MySql on local machine, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Read about docker volumes, or documentation for MySQL docker image. In fact, read both.

Comment: Thanks @Cthulhu, any links would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can solve this problem by using `volumes` in `docker-compose.yaml` file. please refer the following links 
[link1](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#choose-the--v-or-mount-flag),
[link2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).  whenever a docker container runs, it will map the volume to the container. Syntax for the volumes in docker-compose.yaml is as follows:

```
volumes:
 - <path in host>:<path in container>
```

Comment: What path does this refer to?

Comment: path in container means ..the path of data that you want to map to host path

Comment: simply copying data from container to host

Comment: That worked like a charm.  Thanks.  

My next question is, how can I point my applications from within container to the MySql on my localhost?